# ncdu failed to install, with error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: 16.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS on my laptop, updated it just now with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And now I'm trying to install the `ncdu`, but it fails. 
The command I'm using to install the `ncdu` is

```
sudo apt-get install ncdu
```

Even when not using the `sudo` command, it gives same error.

Thanks for help!

**P.S.** This is the second day of my life of using Linux.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu and the fun world of Ubuntu Linux. `sudo apt-get update` updates repository lists, and not your software. That command is usually followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade` (which will upgrade your software within specific rules) or `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` (which will upgrade allowing software version bumps, kernel upgrades etc).  We could help more if you provided more of the text/output before the final segfault.  Please edit your question and include it.

Comment: Thanks! The only line that appears after  'sudo apt-get install ncdu'  is 
 "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".That's it. Also, when trying to update the software as advised, using 'sudo apt-get upgrade' or 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade', error is the same.

Comment: What did the `sudo apt-get update` look like; I'm guessing you didn't see much (ie. it had problems; with little or no sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, but as you're new you didn't recognize it had problems..), eg. my `apt update` contains 51 lines like "Hit:1 http://[redacted]/pub/ubuntu xenial InRelease"(your count will be different as will [redacted] mirror used

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the *full, verbatim* output of `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install ncdu`? You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks eveyone for being so kind to help. I logged out and tried again after having logged back in. This seemed to work, the error no longer appears and I could both upgrade my Ubuntu and install the ncdu. Btw, I would like to apologize from now for the many stupid questions I might ask as a newbie that I am.